# the Objective of this program is supposed to be printing cube

Tags: c++

cube of Randomly generated values which is not happeneing if I return the value from the main function.If I don't return it in the main function and print it in the user defined function then it is working properly. Where I have used pointers its mandatory.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<ctime>
using namespace std;



int* cube(int* ar)
{
    int re[50];
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        re[i] = *(ar + i) * *(ar + i)* *(ar + i);

    }
    return re;
}


int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int ar[50],
        cub[50];
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        ar[i] = (rand() % (99 - 50)) + 50;

    }
    int *ptr;
    cout << "Sr.#\tValue\tCube\n";
    ptr = cube(ar);  // this receives the value being returned from the function
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        cout << i << '\t' << ar[i] << '\t' << *(ptr + i) << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is your question? Clarify the problem and include any error message or issue you're facing.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bad idea to return pointers or references to local variables.
replace

```
int re[50];
```

with

```
int* re=new int[50];
```

Comment: Use `std::vector` to avoid direct allocations.

Comment: It is working bruh.. can U explain what it is?

Comment: which part you want explained? please be more specific

Comment: The line u told me to add. I never used new int .. what is it?

Comment: new allocates memory for an object and returns the address. So new int[50] allocates memory for 50 integers and the returns the address of the first one.